# Flutter web firebase hosting error to load main.dart.js

Tags: html, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web-browser, flutter-exception

How to solve the flutter web firebase hosting error to load main.dart.js, please give me the solution.

I created the first time to complete the work second-time updated the project to show errors like image and not run.

any solution to give me

- [This Type of Error Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spXtY.png)
- [Click to Show Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnATt.png)

**Index.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="flutter_resume_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>flutter_resume_app</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = '2835271624';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="module">

  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "--------------------",
  authDomain: "--------------------",
  projectId: "--------------------",
  storageBucket: "--------------------",
  messagingSenderId: "--------------------",
  appId: "--------------------",
  measurementId: "--------------------"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```